# KeyBindings in Java stop working after component is remade

Tags: key-bindings

My JPanel's KeyBindings work fine until I remove the JPanel from my JFrame, make a new JPanel object and then add that to the JFrame.

The KeyBinding methods run again on the new JPanel object but the Keys don't do anything.

Here are two classes I made to show my problem:

```
public class KeyBindingsTester {

    static JFrame jf;
    static KeyBindingPanel kp;

public static void main(String[] args){
    new KeyBindingsTester(); 
}
public KeyBindingsTester(){

    jf = new JFrame();
    kp = new KeyBindingPanel();

    jf.add(kp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
public static void reset(){
    jf.remove(kp);
    kp = new KeyBindingPanel();
    jf.add(kp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jf.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

--------- AND The Panel:

```
public class KeyBindingPanel extends JPanel{

public KeyBindingPanel(){
    setUpKeyBindings();
    System.out.println("Keybindings set up");
}
public void setUpKeyBindings(){

    addKeyBinding("B");
    addKeyBinding("R");
}
public void addKeyBinding(String key){

    getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key), key);
    getActionMap().put(key, new KeyBindingAction(key));
}

public class KeyBindingAction extends AbstractAction{

    String action;
    public KeyBindingAction(String actionName){
    action = actionName;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(action.equals("R")){
        KeyBindingsTester.reset();
    }
    if(action.equals("B")){
        System.out.println("BBB");
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the focus wasn't on the JPanel in question.

Changing this: getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key), key);
to this:       getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key), key);